# Yii Dropdownlist - showing the column values from a table

Tags: php, yii

I want to add a dropdown list in my page which should show the values from a table column, How can I do this using Yii framework?

I have a table(table name is program) with columns
id, program_name, is_active

I have created a new controller and a view associated with it, I need to show a dropdown list in that view with the values populated from program_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use [`CHtml::dropDownList`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail), possibly with [`CHtml::listData`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to ease the process of creating a `value=>display` array for the [`<options>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option).

Example (see comments in code):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList(
     'somename',// for "name" attribute of <select> html tag,
                // this also becomes the "id" attribute, incase you don't specify
                // it explicitly in the htmlOptions array
     '', // the option element that is to be selected by default
     CHtml::listData( // listData helps in generating the data for <option> tags
        Program::model()->findAll(), // a list of model objects. This parameter
              // can also be an array of associative arrays
              // (e.g. results of CDbCommand::queryAll).
        'id', // the "value" attribute of the <option> tags, 
              // here will be populated with id column values from program table 
        'program_name' // the display text of the <option> tag,
              // here will be populated with program_name column values from table
     ),
     array('id'=>'someid'), // the htmlOptions array, whose values will be
              // generated as html attributes of <select> and <option> tags
);
```

**Edit** Incase you don't have a `CActiveRecord` model for *program* table, you could use [direct sql](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand), replace `Program::model()->findAll()` in the above sample with:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('id, program_name')->from('program')->queryAll()
```

Also if you want to use *program_name* column values as the `value` attribute for the `option` tag, then you can use:

```
CHtml::listData($data,'program_name','program_name') // replaced the 'id' with 'program_name'
```

Comment: i have added a few more details incase the previous version of the answer didn't help

Comment: yes, this is what i am looking for(the edit), but sorry to say that i still have some problems. its not showing the values(program_names).

Comment: <?php
  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('program_id, program_name')->from('program')->queryAll();  
  echo $form->dropDownList($model,'title',CHtml::listData($data,'program_name','program_name'), array('empty'=>'Select a Client'));?> - attaching the code..

Comment: Yes worked, I forgot to assign the value of the query results to $data, when I did that it worked, thanks alot.

Comment: ok, ofcourse you need to either store the result in some variable, or use it directly. Glad i could help.

Comment: hi, how can i put where clause in this query?

Comment: just add a `where()` : `->from('program')->where('mxyzptlk')`, read more in the [CDbCommand doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this at model level. e.g.

In Machine model, I would define a getter :

```
 public function getCompleteMachineName ()
 {
  return $this->merk->name.' '.$this->name;
 }
```

And, in your listData :

```
  Chtml::listData(Machine::model()->with('merk')->findAll(...), 
  'machine_id', 'completeMachineName')
```

Comment: I want to show a dropdown list. when I use the above code it shows fatal error: Chtml is not a member function

Comment: i will have another look for an answer for you. what is the error? it's CHtml with a capital H look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail